# Convert YYYY-MM-DD into YYYYMMDD and insert into Big query partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to perform date conversion of a column from YYYY-MM-DD to YYYYMMDD and insert the final value into a big query partitioned table.

I am getting error as "invalid value" after conversion.

I tried the below,

```
CASE WHEN o_date is not null THEN PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d",cast(a.o_date as string))
ELSE PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d",'19000101')
END as o_date
```

or

```
CASE WHEN o_date is not null THEN cast(FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",o_date) as DATE)
ELSE PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d",'19000101')
END as o_date
```

Could you please help to achieve the same

Cheers!

Comment: Add more accurate tags.

Comment: unable to add big query standard sql tag

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **PARSE_DATE** you can use ***FORMAT_DATE***. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date) it formats a date_expression according to a format string, as follows:

> FORMAT_DATE(format_string, date_expr)

Notice that the *format_string* must be a STRING and it should be written between double quotes following [these formatting elements dictionary](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#supported_format_elements_for_date) and the *date_expr* must be a DATE.

I ran the query below to exemplify how it should be:

```
WITH
  a AS (
  SELECT
    "2020-01-31" AS date )
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CAST(date AS DATE)) AS new_date
FROM
  a
```

I hope it helps.